# Do we need external caching mechanism while EF 6 use caching out of the box?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, caching, entity-framework-6

I recently exposed to Entity Framework 6 [caching mechanism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896269.aspx).
As we might figure from [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh394143.aspx), it does it in First-Lever manner.

Our system uses EF 6 (code first) along with [`MemoryCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) to improve performance.

The main reason we use `MemoryCache` is because we need to execute an intense query on every page request. We execute this query x3 times (in the worst case) on every page request since there are client call backs.

I wonder if we still need to use the `MemoryCache` mechanism if the EF 6 already use one.

It is worth saying that we don't use any special caching feature or cache dependencies. Just a simple `MemoryCache` with timeouts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that EF caches entities in context is in no way a replacement for "real" cache, for various reasons:

1. You should not reuse EF context for more that one logical operation, because EF context represents unit of work, and so should be used according to this pattern. Also, even if you for some reason reuse context in multiple operations - you absolutely cannot do that in multi-threaded environment, like web server application.
2. It does not prevent you from making multiple queries for the same data to your database, for example:

   ```
   var entity1 = ctx.Entities.Where(c => c.Id == 1).First();
   var entity2 = ctx.Entities.Where(c => c.Id == 1).First();
   ```

   This will still execute two queries to your database, despite the fact that query is the same and returns the same entity. So nothing is really "cached" in usual sense here. Note however, that both queries will return the *same* entity, even if database row has been changed between two queries. That is what is meant by EF context "caching". It will execute database query two times, but second time, while evaluating the result, it will notice that there is already entity with the same key attached to the context. So it will return this existing ("cached") entity instead, and will ignore new values (if any) returned by the second query. That behaviour is additional reason to not reuse the context between multiple operations (though you should not do it anyway).

So if you want to reduce load on your database - you have to use second-level caching using whatever suits your needs (from simple InMemoryCache to caching EF provider to distributed memcached instance).

Comment: Thank you for that. I actually surprised about the second section, If I execute one query and then change value in the DB and execute the same query again, it brings me the same results, without the changes. Does it still refer to DB in the second time? Although it gave me un-updated data?

Comment: @Jacob I updated that part to answer you question, hope it's clear enough. If you still have some worries about that - it's easy to verify yourself - just set up logging (like `context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine`) then execute the same query twice and you will see that two database queries are executed.

Comment: Best explained. Thank you very much!

Comment: I checked it and you're correct, it does go to the DB on the second time. Do you have any idea why does EF does it if it's not going to use the results anyway it can estimate it before doing the trip that the trip is not  necessary?

Answer (score 4):

EF only implements what is called first level cache for entities, It stores the entities which have been retrieved during the life time of a context so when you ask for that entity the second time it returns the entity from context. What you need is a second level cache but EF dosen't implants this features. NCache for example implements a wonderful caching architecture and a out of the box a second level cache provider for EF. Not in its open source version.